# Scalability Blazeds | 3000 messages | 1 min

Tags: blazeds

I am using Blazeds-3.2.0.3978 amd Weblogic 10.0.0.1. I have the session timeout
for 5 minutes.

Below is channel definition i am using

```
channel-definition id="my-polling-amf"
class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel"

endpoint
url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amfpolling"
class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/


polling-enabled true polling-enabled

polling-interval-seconds 1 polling-interval-seconds
```

I have declared destination as

```
destination id="destICL"
adapter ref="actionscript" /

message-time-to-live 120000 message-time-to-live
```

Generally 10-15 users uses the system simultaneously. The server side code sends
approx 3000 messages in one second on the destination. Everthing works fine but
some time the client misses few messages. It happens sometimes. It is difficult
to reproduce also. But any client cannot afford to loose message. I can send you
the conference files for your reference.Any blaze expert can provide any
pointer???

Thanks
ilikeflex

Comment: Can you increase logging verbosity in BlazeDS and see if there is any information about the missing messages there?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Streaming channel for messaging as that is more reliable. Moreover you don't have many parallel clients (10-15) so even thread blockage on BlazeDS server won't be a problem.

FYI: I am using Flex, BlazeDS Spring, Java combination.